# Processing not launching after OSX Update to 10.9.1

Tags: java, macos, processing, osx-mavericks

I have been usign the default download of Processing from their website but after reinstalling and completely updating my Mac the IDE will not load. Deleting the Processing folders (sketches, tools, the lot) doesn't help.. Processing does recreate them but then hangs doing nothing. Relaoding then jsut closes after opening again.

Running processing from terminal I see a NullPointerException, the main dump being the following:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at processing.app.Base.<init>(Base.java:351)
    at processing.app.Base.createAndShowGUI(Base.java:202)
    at processing.app.Base.access$0(Base.java:145)
    at processing.app.Base$1.run(Base.java:139)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at processing.core.PApplet.parseInt(PApplet.java:9374)
    at processing.app.contrib.AvailableContribution.<init>(AvailableContribution.java:51)
    at processing.app.contrib.ContributionListing.parseContribList(ContributionListing.java:460)
    at processing.app.contrib.ContributionListing.setAdvertisedList(ContributionListing.java:76)
    at processing.app.contrib.ContributionListing.<init>(ContributionListing.java:59)
    at processing.app.contrib.ContributionListing.getInstance(ContributionListing.java:66)
    at processing.app.contrib.ContributionManager.<clinit>(ContributionManager.java:35)
    ... 18 more
```

Any help will be appreciataed, i've tried everything I've found online, including downloadind a new JDK but OSX won't mount my download, and it shouln't need me to update the JDK anyway, the correct version of java being built into Mavericks already.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know java is not build into Maverick ;)

Maybe I'm wrong but every time after fresh install when I want to run Java program Java starts the installation itself. It seems that Maverick will call needed installation process when needed on demand.

Try installing JDownloader. That usually triggers Java installation for me.

Comment: Yup. Not only is it not built into it but it uninstalls any previous Java installs on upgrade. PITA really.